# Why does node js behave like this?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following code

```js
function getCleanObject() {
    var obj = {};
    for (var _i = 0, _a = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj.__proto__); _i < _a.length; _i++) {
        var prop = _a[_i];
        obj[prop] = undefined;
    }
    obj.__proto__ = undefined;
    return obj;
}
var a = 1;
console.log(getCleanObject(a).__proto__);
//'undefined' in browser
//'{}' in nodejs
```

A simple function which returns object and everything is stripped off or set to `undefined`. When this is executed in a browser console, we get `undefined` which is expected because `__proto__` is set to `undefined`, but when we execute the same code in node, we get `{}`, I'm confused why this happens.

This was part of `picoCTF lambdash 3` CTF competition

Comment: Don't use `obj.__proto__ = undefined;` Apart from `__proto__` being deprecated, just start with `var obj = Object.create(null)`. Use `Object.getPrototypeOf` to access the prototype chain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getCleanObject` doesn't make much sense because it assigns properties and then tries to unset object prototype, this will result in an object with a lot of garbage keys.

`__proto__` is [non-compliant property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) that may exist in some implementations but shouldn't be relied on. Proper ways to access object prototype are `Object.getPrototypeOf` and `Object.setPrototypeOf`.

`__proto__` will work in V8 (Node.js, Chrome) because they support it. It is a descriptor on `Object.prototype`:

```
({}).hasOwnProperty('__proto__') === false
(Object.prototype).hasOwnProperty('__proto__') === true
```

It doesn't allow arbitrary values to be assigned to it, only `null` and objects:

> The **proto** property of Object.prototype is an accessor property (a getter function and a setter function) that exposes the internal [[Prototype]] (either an object or null) of the object through which it is accessed.

`obj.__proto__ = undefined` is incorrect and shouldn't be expected to work. It may work in Node as `obj.__proto__ = null`. And the correct way is `Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, null)`.

If there's no existing object that should be modified (modifying prototypes is discouraged because this can kill optimizations) as in `getCleanObject` then it could be:

```
const obj = Object.create(null);
```

Comment: "*It doesn't allow any value to be assigned to it*" - do you mean that it doesn't allow `undefined` as a value?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for noticing, it was 'any arbitrary value' once.

Comment: Thanks!
This was part of a ctf competition, you can read the write up here - https://github.com/Minemaniak/writeups/tree/master/picoCTF2018/LambDash3

Comment: @SpaceChuppy Yes, I see. As I mentioned, `obj.__proto__ = null` would work in Node but not `obj.__proto__ = undefined`, this also would make `for` useless.  Is it safe to assume that `getCleanObject` was badly coded on purpose to be obscure but exploitable?